# Devemos aceitar perguntas de web design?

Tags: debate

## Introdução

De vez em quando aqui no SOpt me deparo com perguntas que são mais consideradas design / layout ou *UI* do que programação. (*Interface de usuário)

Alguns exemplos um pouco duvidosos, por não estar no contexto de programação e ao mesmo tempo estar:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25480/scroll-horizontal
- [Como espaçar o "título fixo" de uma página e as postagens?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25516/como-espa%C3%A7ar-o-t%C3%ADtulo-fixo-de-uma-p%C3%A1gina-e-as-postagens) (acredito que essa nem devia estar com a tag PHP pois a duvida se trata de WebDesign..)

Apesar dessas perguntas não serem especificamente de programação, elas (meio que) podem se encaixar nesse tópico do guia [Perguntando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

- Ferramentas comuns entre programadores

Já que o HTML é uma ferramenta de programadores Web para mostrar seu conteúdo (na minha opinião).

## Discussão

Primeiramente, vale lembrar que no área51 existe um [projeto para WebDesign](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58647/web-designing) o que já me leva a pensar que isso realmente é algo separado e que uma outra comunidade poderia surgir a partir disso.

Então, já que *provavelmente* Web design não tem muito a ver com programação vou voltar ao titulo:

- **Devemos aceitar perguntas de web design?**
- *E o que devemos fazer com as que ja existem e as proximas  a serem perguntadas*?

#### Nota:

Essa é minha primeira perugunta no Meta, então não sei muito bem como as coisas funcionam aqui, se minha pergunta está no contexto, etc. Qualquer coisa comentem por favor.

E como podem ter vária opiniõs sobre isso, vou esperar 48h (ou 36h) para marcar uma resposta como certa ou até então nem marcar nenhuma, áar ver qual recebe mais votos / suporte.

Comment: O tópico "Experiência e interface com usuário/utilizador." recebeu 31 votos positivos e 0 negativos na [votação de assuntos on-topic](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/269/429).

Comment: Bom, mas no final do tópico está escrito `Se discorda de algum item, coloque-o em votação, Mas já adianto que ele foi testado antes e foi bem aceito.` então acho que não faz mal abrir um discussão. mas como você disse, a votação foi para "Experiência e interface com usuário/utilizador." acredito que WebDesign seja algo um pouco mais especifico para ser discutido, porque ele não depende de linguagem como aconteceria numa interface "C++ / Qt" ou "Swing e Java".

Comment: Não sou contra a discussão, apenas apontei um fato. Uma opinião minha: nenhuma das duas perguntas que você lincou é sobre web design. Ambas são problemas específicos de código onde o web design é apenas o contexto. Elas claramente perguntam "como modificar meu código para fazer X?". Perguntas de design geralmente são mais abertas, por exemplo: ["como indicar visualmente o que o usuário deve preencher?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6667) ou ["mensagens de erro devem pedir desculpas?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2539) (são dois exemplos que lembrei agora). Acho construtivas.

Comment: Apesar de ser um desenvolvedor primariamente de *back end*, não é incomum eu me deparar com problemas de *layout* envolvendo HTML e CSS. Isso faz parte da rotina de desenvolvimento de sistemas web. Por outro lado, acho que perguntas de *design* do tipo "aplicar filtro no photoshop" estão fora do escopo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu concordo com [o comentário do @GuilhermeBernal](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/devemos-aceitar-perguntas-de-web-design#comment4918_1711) a respeito das perguntas citadas não serem sobre Web Design, e sim sobre dificuldades técnicas com determinada tecnologia. Talvez por estarem imersas no contexto de criação de páginas HTML você tenha essa impressão, mas as dúvidas envolvem mais como fazer para obter um determinado *layout* (ou como solucionar uma dificuldade com ele) do que discutir o porquê dele ser de um jeito ou de outro (o que, em minha visão, recairia mais no sentido de web design). Dito isso, mesmo que as perguntas fossem especificamente sobre Web Design, elas provevalmente seriam *on-topic* por envolver aspectos de [usabilidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/usabilidade) e/ou [ux](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ux), que têm sido aceitos como relevantes pela comunidade tanto na votação no meta quanto na existência de algumas perguntas no site.

Sobre a existência de uma proposta na Área51 específica para Web Design, eu acho que o ponto principal para essa discussão é que o SOPT permite que o conteúdo seja construído no nosso próprio idioma e esse é justamente o grande motivador. Recentemente fui "lembrado" em uma pergunta minha sobre [latex](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex) de que [já existe uma comunidade](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) para esse tipo de dúvida no grupo SE. Isso é verdade, e quando eu postei a pergunta eu cheguei mesmo a ponderar por fazê-lo lá porque (1) eu tenho facilidade com o idioma e (2) talvez tivesse uma resposta mais rápida. Mas, já que existe a possibilidade de fazê-lo aqui e também existem outras pessoas interessadas no assunto, por que não dar preferência pela nossa comunidade? Tive uma resposta satisfatória que me ajudou com a minha dúvida em particular e o conhecimento foi mantido pra ajudar outras pessoas que não têm a mesma facilidade com inglês.

Sendo assim, a minha opinião é que devemos sim aceitar perguntas sobre Web Design, mesmo que não envolvam apenas critérios técnicos ligados às tecnologias de construção de páginas como HTML, CSS, PHP, etc. Já faz um bom tempo que design tem a ver com desenvolvimento de software porque se entende que não basta a um produto ser funcional, ele também tem de ser seguro, fácil de usar, eficiente, etc. Mas, além disso, é cada vez mais importante considerar que a satisfação vai além da mera ausência de desconforto, principalmente quando o seu produto tem concorrentes funcionalmente equivalentes e seu uso é de livre arbítrio do utilizador (*discretionary*).

Comment: Concordo inteiramente com os dois primeiros parágrafos. Sobre aceitarmos perguntas de web design "puro" tenho muito receio. Embora me interesse pelo tema, acho que foge muito no nosso foco, que é programação (latex foge bem menos, já que é uma linguagem de markup). Mas estou falando em abstrato, precisaríamos ver algumas perguntas concretas. Podemos debater os exemplos do [site de design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) como forma de levar adiante a discussão.

Comment: @bfavaretto Hum... acho que precisamos primeiro ter um bom entendimento do que é esse tal de Web Design "puro", não? :) Na minha defesa do último parágrafo eu confesso que não estava pensando [em questões meramente artísticas](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35990/creating-a-rainbow-like-background) do "design", mas principalmente [em questões estéticas relevantes para a interação humano-computador](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/323/new-generation-of-save-icon-that-is-not-a-disk).

Comment: P.S.: Muito embora, eu ainda acharia interessante no escopo do SOPT a primeira questão que eu exemplifiquei no meu comentário acima se ela fosse sobre como criar um gradiente em certa linguagem/ferramenta de programação... :)